# Property of linear projections

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Theorem 15 in Chapter 15 of Peter Lax's functional analysis book says

$X$ is a Banach space, $Y$ and $Z$ are  closed subspaces of $X$ that complement each other $X = Y \oplus Z$, in the sense that every $x\in X$ can be decomposed uniquely as $x = y+z$ where $y\in Y$, $z\in Z$. Denote the two complements of $y$ and $z$ of $x$ by $y = P_Y x$, $z = P_Z x$. Then

1) $P_Y$ and $P_Z$ are linear maps of $X$ on $Y$ and $Z$ respectively.

2) $P_Y^2 = P_Y$, $P_Z^2 = P_Z$, $P_YP_Z = 0$.

3) $P_Y$ and $P_Z$ are continuous.

However, I would like to say that for all $\hat y\in Y$, 
$\|y-x\| \leq \|\hat y - x\|$.

which is a property of projections we already know, but doesn't seem to be built from the definition of projections given by Lax. I'm not too familiar with Banach spaces, so I don't really want to use this property until I know for sure it is implied by the previous properties.

Can anyone give me some intuition if 1) this property is implied by the definitions, 2) this property may not hold in some special case (Not sure if $X$ is reflexive), or 3) this is implicit in the definition of projection and I'm just reading the text wrong?

Thanks!

Edit: Just to add clarification, I'm considering any complemented Banach space (infinite dimensional). Not necessarily a Hilbert space, and no indication that it is reflexive.

Comment: After playing around with it, I can use the properties to arrive at the following: $\|x-y\| > \|x-\hat y\|$ but $\|P_Y(x-\hat y)\| > \|P_Y(x-y)\|$. I feel like this should lead me to a contradiction but I can't figure one out.

Comment: What do you mean by orthogonal? Is this a Hilbert space?

Comment: No just that $P_YP_Z x = 0$ and $P_ZP_Y x = 0$. Definitely not a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property doesn't necessarily hold, and for counterexample you can take $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ as a Banach space.

The above $P_Y,P_Z$ are linear projections, and they have the desired property if and only if they are *orthogonal* projections.

Assume that $P_Y,P_Z$ are orthogonal projections, in other words $Y$ is orthogonal to $Z$. Then for all $\hat{y}\in Y$, $$\|\hat{y}-x\|^2=\|\hat{y}-y\|^2+\|y-x\|^2\geq\|y-x\|^2$$by Pythagoras.

Remark: For the term *orthogonal* to be relevant, we need to assume that $X$ is Hilbert, not only Banach.

Comment: Sorry! I just added an edit because I forgot to include the orthogonal property.

Comment: @noob Right. See my edit please.

Comment: ah I see! Yeah I think I'm misusing the term "orthogonal" then; I edited the question to be more specific. I don't think we can use Pythagoras for non-Hilbert spaces? Thank you for your help!

Comment: For the claim to hold we need the projections to be orthogonal, and for that to make any sense, we need the space to be Hilbert.

Comment: It is possible to have projections with the above properties without any notion of orthogonality. See the addendum to my answer below.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't understand what you're saying. The examples you give *don't* satisfy the property in question (as you show explicitly).

Comment: @AmitaiYuval: I'm not sure what you mean, my second example is a case where the projections satisfy 1)-3) above and violate the smallest norm requirement. My point is that $P_Z P_Y = P_Y P_Z = 0$ doesn't imply that the projection has minimum norm (not a Hilbert space, of course).

Comment: @copper.hat I think each one of us emphesises a different aspect of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y= \operatorname{sp} \{ (1,0)^T \}$, $Z= \operatorname{sp} \{ (1,1)^T \}$.

Then $P_Y(x) = (x_1-x_2) (1,0)^T$, $P_Z(x) = x_2 (1,1)^T$.

Pick $x=(0,1)^T$, which gives $y=(-1,0)$, $z=(1,1)^T$.

Then
$\|y-x\| = \|z\| = \sqrt{2}$, but with $\hat{y} = (0,0)^T$, we have
$\|\hat{y} -x\| = 1 < \sqrt{2}$.

**Addendum**:

Here is an example where $P_Y P_Z = P_Z P_Y = 0$:

Let $Y=\operatorname{sp} \{ (1,0)^T \}$, $Z=\operatorname{sp} \{ (0,1)^T \}$, then
$P_Y(x) = (x_1,0)^T$, $P_Z(x) = (0, x_2)^T$.

Let $\|x\|_* = \|(x_1-x_2, x_2)\|_2$.

Choose $x=(1,1)^T$, then $z = P_Z(x) = (0,1)^T$, so
$\|y-x\|_*=\|z\|_* =\sqrt{2}$. If we let $\hat{y} = (0,0)^T \in Y$, then
$\|\hat{y}-x\|_* = 1 < \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: This is a really nice geometric example, thank you! What happens if we then assume that $P_Y$ and $P_X$ are orthogonal projections though? Still no Hilbert space so I can't just expand the norm and use inner products...

Comment: I don't have time now, but pick $Y,Z$ to be the usual axes and use a norm like $\|x\|_* = \|(x_1, x_2-x_2)^T\|_2$.

Comment: Actually it occurred to me that your first counterexample is the reason why there is no way that property can hold, since those properties of projections are supposed to follow just from $X$ being complemented. :( Thanks for your help!